# Solution for connecting two computers (work laptop and personal computer) 2 monitors, keyboard & mouse and a webcam

Tags: multiple-monitors, kvm, docking-stations

I'm starting a new job soon where the device I'll receive is a Dell XPS laptop with USB C type connectors, I believe it'll be something similar to the Dell XPS 15 lineup.

I have two Dell U2414H "Ultrasharp" monitors, these are both connected to my computer's GPU through an HDMI and a DisplayPort cable. My mouse and keyboard are both using USB 3 and USB 2, I believe. Right now, all these devices/monitors connect directly into the back of my computer's motherboard and GPU, respectively and have worked for years without issue.

My current desktop computer does not have USB C ports, but I may be upgrading it in a few months to a case/mobo with that functionality.

From the copious amount of googling I've been doing, I've come across either Docking Stations or KVM "Switches", but the latter seem to be very expensive, and the former... well I'm not really sure what I need there, hence this post. I've found a few docking stations like this [product on Amazon, a 12 in 1 USB hub that seems to have 2 HDMI ports](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B08BF8XMZP/ref=twister_B099ZH9HXK?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1).

What I'm looking for is a device or other solution, effectively:

- A device that lets me plug in 2 monitors, a keyboard and a mouse (also a pair of headphones and a webcam, if possible)
- This device then plugs into both my desktop computer (standard USB) and my work laptop (most likely all USB C ports, so I'd assume USB-USB C/USB C-USB adapters will be necessary)
- I can then easily swap between both my work laptop and personal computer at the push of a button on said-device. If not possible, I could just swap a cable between both devices whenever necessary
- Doesn't cost as much as a new laptop

Are there any devices/combination of devices that let me do such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

So after some hours searching around I ended up going with a combination of two devices, since a switch with 2 HDMIs and a couple of USB ports costs a few hundred at the least, stupidly.

[First off is this USB hub that will plug into my laptop.](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Docking-Station-Adapter-MOKiN-DisplayPort/dp/B089CHQ67F/ref=pd_lpo_3?pd_rd_i=B089CHQ67F&psc=1) I'm going to buy another couple of HDMI cables to plug directly into this, then leave the cables that come from my monitors currently going into my computer as they are. This way, I'll have to manually change the source for each monitor. Not ideal, but cheaper than the asinine KVM solutions that cost in excess of 300 pounds.

[Secondly is this 4 input/2 output KVM switch.](https://www.amazon.co.uk/UGREEN-Sharing-Keyboard-Scanner-Printer-Black/dp/B01N6GD9JO/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=kvm%20switch%20usb&qid=1631492275&sr=8-3) Minus the "V" in "KVM", this thing will have my keyboard and mouse plugged into it. The KVM will then plug into both my personal computer and the laptop's USB hub.

With this combination, I can swap my mouse and keyboard inputs between my personal PC and my work PC. Then whenever I'm done with my work laptop, I can just shut it down and change the input source on my monitors.

So instead of one device, unfortunately, I'm buying 2 more HDMI cables, a USB C hub and a KVM switch. Lovely. Hope this helps someone navigating this minefield of input/output/cables/devices/KVMs/docking stations/whatever else in the future.